# Can I access the value of a JSON model in my controller?

Tags: json, xml, sapui5

I want to redirect to a link (Employee Address Book page) with the employee id as parameter.

My xml view has the following code code:

```
<Label text="{i18n>requestor}"/>    
<HBox>
    <items>
        <Text text="{path:'itemModel>/item/empData/EmployeeName'} ({path:'itemModel>/item/empData/EmployeeID'})"/>
        <Button type="Transparent" icon="sap-icon://sys-help" press="onHelpPress"/>
    </items>
</HBox>
```

This gives me an output as:

```
Request Created By: xyz(E123)
```

where xyz is the employee name and comes from the json model set to the view `(itemModel): itemModel>/item/empData/EmployeeName`

and E123 is the employee id which comes from the same json model: `itemModel>/item/empData/EmployeeID`

Now I have a help button which on click will redirect to the employee address book with the parameter `EmployeeID` someting like:

```
https://employeeaddressbook.sdf.sicom.com/profiles/E123
```

My controller code for handling the event which is not working:

```
onHelpPress: function(oEvent) { 

    // var  
    userid=this.getView().getModel('itemModel').getProperty("/item/empData/EmployeeID");
    //  window.open("https://employeeaddressbook.sdf.sicom.com/profiles/" + userid ,"_new");
}
```

Can anyone please let me know how to access the value of the model property EmployeeID in the controller and redirect it with the parameter?

Answer (score -2):

Smith,
Declare Id for Text, onHelpPress event call that id as 
var EmployeeID = this.getView().by("Idname").getText() - you will get text Take the Required text and use this 
sap.m.URLHelper.redirect("https://employeeaddressbook.sdf.sicom.com/profiles/"+EmployeeID +"")

Comment: I did give an id to button but no success.